# Swift. Declaring private functions in internal protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

How can I achieve something like this (doesn't compile):

```
internal protocol InternalPrivateMix {
    private func doPrivately()
    internal func doInternaly()
}
```

Basically I want to kind of make a promise that confirming class implements some functionality privately. This is more for self documentation. I obviously can just implement these functions in my classes without formally conform to protocol and write documentation describing that every class should implement this functionality. Though it would be nice if I could communicate my intent to other developers more formally.

EDIT: I have tried to implement two protocols in one file, one private, one internal as @creeperspeak suggested. However I cannot conform to private protocol in other files so it doesn't work.

Comment: According to Apple's Docs:

If you want to assign an explicit access level to a protocol type, do so at the point that you define the protocol. This enables you to create protocols that can only be adopted within a certain access context.

The access level of each requirement within a protocol definition is automatically set to the same access level as the protocol. You cannot set a protocol requirement to a different access level than the protocol it supports. This ensures that all of the protocol’s requirements will be visible on any type that adopts the protocol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From Apple's docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html#ID22) it looks like the only way to achieve what you are trying to do is to implement 2 protocols - one internal, and one private, as Apple states "You cannot set a protocol requirement to a different access level than the protocol it supports."

Comment: I have tried it before, but I cannot conform to private protocol in fileA if it is in fileB. Is there any other way? As far as I can see, there is no.

Comment: It sounds a little bit like you don't want it to be a private protocol.  By definition "private" means that it's not accessible from other files.  If you really want the private protocol to be only available from a single file, but you want another class to inherit it, you can make it fileprivate and implement an extension of the inheriting class in the same file to handle that.

Comment: Well, yes, I don't want a private protocol in 'Swift' meaning of it. I want to be able to mark functions private in an internal protocol. This seems to be impossible in current Swift version.

Comment: @creeperspeak can you please give a link to the doc?

Comment: @SubhajitHalder Edited answer to include link.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
protocol P {
    func int()
}

extension P {
    func int() {
        print("int()")
        priv()
    }
    private func priv() {
        print("priv()")
    }
}
```

Which might serve your purpose - I use it.

Comment: This doesn’t make any sense. I still can access init() and the init will still do what I don’t wanna do.

Comment: The purpose is that people who accept a P for a function argument or variable definition cannot call priv, but the writer of an extension to P can. Normally the writer of P also the writer of the extension to P. Agree it's all a bit strange but that is Swift!