# Can you declare a function with private in a protocol

Tags: swift

I want to create a protocol which declares a private function. When a class conforms to that protocol, the function declaration is required to be in private. When I do it this way it throws an error saying that I can't put private in the protocol. Any suggestions?

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    private func printHello() 
}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
    private func printHello() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us why you want a protocol to declare a private method and we might be able to advise some way to solve that problem. But a protocol is, essentially, a way to declare public interface to which types can conform, so it’s a bit of a contradiction of terms to say that you want it specify some private implementation detail like some private method.

Comment: Basically I have a class that I want to conform to this protocol. I want to make the method private so it's not accessible by other places

Comment: The method is already part of the protocol, so you're not going to see it from anything other than something that conforms to `SomeProtocol`

Comment: The protocol just requires classes that conforms to it to declare it. Keep it as 'internal' which is the default means it's still accessible from other places. That's why I want it to be private because it's ever only called within its own class and not out of it.

Comment: If it’s only used within the class, then it doesn’t belong in the protocol. The purpose of the protocol is to declare how it’s accessible elsewhere. Why do you want to put a private method in the protocol? A class that conforms to this protocol can have whatever private methods it needs and they don’t need to be part of the protocol.

Comment: Here's an example: I have 5 classes that both share the same method so I would definitely want to put this in a protocol. But instead of an internal method I want to make it private so it acts as a private helper method for the class. So yes, I do want to create a protocol so my 5 classes conform to and I DO want the method to be private. So now how can we do that

Comment: Put those five classes in the same file as you defined your protocol and then you can use a private extension, making that shared method accessible to those five classes but not outside of it as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46996675/1271826). But it doesn’t belong in the protocol itself, just in the extension. The protocol is for the public interface only. You might not be entirely happy with that answer, but that’s how it works, at this point at least.